# v-for in vue 2 could not pass values dynamically to @change function

Tags: vue.js, v-for

In vue2, I have used v-for on a div and there is a button with a function  in that div. passing values to that function are not dynamic.

Have a look on my code. I am working in vue2.

```
<div class="revision-row completed-revision" v-for="(revision, index) in singleOrder.revisions" :key="index">
    <div class="reveision-button" :data-rvv="revision.id" v-if="revision.status == 'Payment Done'">
        <div class="revision-payment-btn">
            
            <input class="white-field" style="display:none" multiple accept="image/*,video/*"
                   @change="submitRevision(singleOrder.id,revision.id,index,$event)" type="file" name="fileinputnew"
                   id="revisionImage">
            <label for="revisionImage" class="imgs-uploaderss">
                Submit Drawing
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`submitRevision(a,b,c,c){ alert(a) }`

alert always prints the first one div's `singleOrder.id` value and could not change dynamically for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you use the same ID on the different html elements. It is not recommended. [Discussion about ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme).

Solution: 
**:id="`revisionImage${revision.id}`"** 
**:for="`revisionImage${revision.id}`"**

Be sure that revision.ids are unique

Try this:

````
<div class="revision-row completed-revision" v-for="(revision, index) in singleOrder.revisions" :key="index">
    <div class="reveision-button" :data-rvv="revision.id" v-if="revision.status == 'Payment Done'">
        <div class="revision-payment-btn">
            
            <input class="white-field" style="display:none" multiple accept="image/*,video/*"
                   @change="submitRevision(singleOrder.id,revision.id,index,$event)" type="file" name="fileinputnew"
                   :id="`revisionImage${revision.id}`">
            <label :for="`revisionImage${revision.id}`" class="imgs-uploaderss">
                Submit Drawing
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>```
````